# PHP ending sessions?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

In every PHP script I run for this web app I'm writing, I have the code

```
session_set_cookie_params(86400);
session_start();
```

To me, that way, when a user is logged in and using the site, it should keep them logged in 24 hours after the last time they use the site.  But for some reason, it only keeps the session 24 hours after they first log in.  As it is now… if they're using the site 24 hours after they logged in, all of a sudden it just logs them out.  Is there a way to refresh the timeout time on every page load or something that I don't know about?  I thought it happened every time I run the above code, but apparently not.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the way that `session_set_cookie_params` works, it's expiry isn't updated on each page visit properly. You need to use `setcookie` for this and pass along the parameters necessary, for instance, here's a snippet from the documentation for `session_set_cookie_params`

```
$lifetime = 86400; 
session_start();
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$lifetime);
```

This should resolve your issue.

[Reference here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#100657)

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try this and come back tomorrow with the results :)